# How to split a row into 2 based on an if condition

Tags: mysql

I am struck with following process. I have two tables named table1 & table2.
table1 consists total amount with current status. table2 consists filled amount.
I want to get the result like, if the `table1.status = 'cancel'` then I need to get 2 rows as showed in expected result. Is there any way to do that?

table1

```
unq_id | amount | status  | type
   1      4       'cancel'  'two'
   2      2       'done'    'one'
```

table2

```
p_id | unq_id | filled
  1      1      1   
  2      2      2
```

My query

```
SELECT 
  a.unq_id as id_val,
  (IFNULL(b.filled,0)) as filled 
FROM 
  table1 AS a 
  LEFT JOIN table2 AS b 
    ON a.unq_id = b.unq_id 
WHERE 
  (a.status = "done" 
  OR a.status = "cancel")
```

current result

```
id_val | filled
  1      1
  2      2
```

expected result

```
id_val filled
  1      3 (cancelled amount [ 4 - filled amount])
  1      1 (filled amount)
  2      2
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can use a query like below

```
SELECT 
  a.unq_id as id_val,
  ABS(opt-IFNULL(b.filled,0)) as filled
FROM 
  (select *, 0 as opt from table1 
   union all
   select *,4 as opt from table1 where status = "cancel")AS a 
  LEFT JOIN table2 AS b 
    ON a.unq_id = b.unq_id 
WHERE 
  (a.status = "done" 
  OR a.status = "cancel")
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use Union...
First part of query you already have, giving you part of your result. You just need to add second query to it to fetch rest of the result:

```
SELECT a.unq_id as id_val,(ISNULL(b.filled,0)) as filled FROM 
Tab1 AS a LEFT JOIN Tab2 AS b ON a.unq_id = b.unq_id 
WHERE (a.status = "done" OR a.status = "cancel")

UNION

SELECT a.unq_id as id_val, a.amount - b.filled as filled FROM 
Tab1 AS a LEFT JOIN Tab2 AS b ON a.unq_id = b.unq_id 
WHERE (a.status = 'cancel')

ORDER BY id_val
```

Comment: You can use `UNION ALL` here. There won't be any duplication here I guess.

Comment: Both of the Vineet & @DhruvJoshi answers are working fine for me. Little bit confused about the efficiency of both queries.Which will be better ?